# Keyboard not working properly when remoting into Ubuntu 12.10 via tightvnc

Tags: keyboard, remote

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to fix. I am running into the problem outlined [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1595871) and there is a solution posted by user ecadman. However, the steps to fix it are:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. `gconf-editor`
3. /->app->metacity->global_keybindings
4. Change the assigned keystroke for show_desktop from <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or `disabled`.

and I do **not** have a `global_keybindings` folder under metacity. I also am missing a `gnome_settings` folder under `apps`, which was another workaround.

Other notable problems, all keyboard related, are: I cannot access the keyboard layout settings, and the on-screen keyboard has all question marks over the letters and says `X keyboard cannot be found, retrying` on the spacebar.

Other than the <kbd>D</kbd> key not causing input and instead triggering the shortcut, the rest of the keyboard works fine. I even went into the keyboard settings in both gnome and Ibus and disabled the `hide all windows` shortcut (in gnome settings) and tried to disable the <kbd>D</kbd> key from triggering shortcuts (in Ibus settings).

I'm not really sure where to go from here. It's a standard en-us keyboard. I also do not have local access to this machine, but do have full ssh access and can add whatever else I need if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. While I was simply disabling the key bindings for hide all windows, I simply needed to rebind it to some arbitrary combination and the problem stopped. Hope that helps anyone with the same issue.