# All minimize button

Tags: shortcuts

Is there any button in Ubuntu like in windows which is present in right-bottom corner to minimize all windows?

If it is there please tell me, it will be of great use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Super+D at the same time. It is the shortcut to minimize all windows.

Comment: It's working, I am connected to two linux machines through tightvnc and the above command is working for one machine but not on other. Can you help with this? @Muzaffar

Comment: I have never tried  virtual desktops, but maybe this link helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/246800/keyboard-not-working-properly-when-remoting-into-ubuntu-12-10-via-tightvnc

Answer (score 1):

You can define hot-corner with custom command using [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] and 
[wmctrl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wmctrl) [image: Install wmctrl] package to minimize all windows(show the desktop)

From [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/wmctrl.1.html)

```
-k  ( on  |  off  )
              Turn  on or off the window manager's "show the desktop" mode (if
              the window manager implements this feature).
```

- Install
  [`compizconfig-settings-manager`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/compiz)
  and [`wmctrl`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/wmctrl) using

  ```
  sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager wmctrl
  ```
- Open `compizconfig-settings-manager` by entering `ccsm` in dash.
- Search for **Commands** in ***ccsm window*** .
- In *Command line 0*  type

  ```
  wmctrl -k on
  ```
- Click on *Edge Bindings* tab and define hot corner (right-bottom corner as you said ) for this command.
  Moving mouse in defined corner  will minimize all windows.

Comment: Sorry, g_p I don't have permission to install anything