# Cannot open my desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys

I am not able to open my desktop using a shortcut. Ubuntu does not have hide all windows option in it. what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/571700/all-minimize-button/571703#571703

Comment: It does the combination is ctrl + Win (super) + D

Comment: The shortcut you are looking for is under Navigation, not Windows